# Boundaries of string indexes in java

Tags: java, substring, indexoutofboundsexception

This code...

```
public String a() {
String x = "abc";
String y = x.substring(3,3);
return y; //returns : "" 
}
```

Works without errors but i thought there is no 3rd index for that string.As i understand indexes of strings like 1st char is 0 index ,2nd char 1 index,it goes like that.Then why is not that giving me a error like "OutOfBoundsException"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the code, and you will see that it does not meet the requirement for an Exception

```
 public String substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex) {
    if (beginIndex < 0) {
        throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(beginIndex);
    }
    if (endIndex > value.length) {
        throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(endIndex);
    }
    int subLen = endIndex - beginIndex;
    if (subLen < 0) {
        throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(subLen);
    }
    return ((beginIndex == 0) && (endIndex == value.length)) ? this
            : new String(value, beginIndex, subLen);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation:

> IndexOutOfBoundsException - if the beginIndex is negative, or endIndex
>   is larger than the length of this String object, or beginIndex is
>   larger than endIndex.

None of these conditions have been met.